# Xdebug + Netbeans on Ubuntu

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to debug my code using xdebug in NetBeans, but it's unresponsive. I'm using the current releases of Netbeans and Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get xdebug on ubuntu working with phpstorm and netbeans 7.2 , refer to this post on how to configure this. This is the tutorial i < href="http://purencool.com/installing-xdebug-on-ubuntu">followed.